# Session attribute set in a spring filter extending AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter not available in SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I am trying to set a value in session in a custom Spring filter which extends AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.

```
public class OpenIdConnectFilter extends AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter {
    public OAuth2RestOperations restTemplate;

    public OpenIdConnectFilter(String defaultFilterProcessesUrl) {
        super(defaultFilterProcessesUrl);
        setAuthenticationManager(new NoopAuthenticationManager());
    }

    @Override
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws AuthenticationException, IOException, ServletException {
            request.getSession().setAttribute("Sample_Attribute", "Hello World");
    }
```

I have a class AuthenticationSuccessHandler (which extends SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler) where I want to get the value of the session attribute but here when I do

```
request.getSession().getAttribute("Sample_Attribute")
```

I get null.

How can I set the value in session or pass the value from the filter to the handler.

Thanks

Comment: Could you please share your security configuration ?

Comment: In your `attemptAuthentication` method print `request.getSession(false)` if it prints null, then understand you are setting attribute before session has been created. That means you are creating new session and setting attribute later it will be overridden i guess.